# How to customise the UITableView's Separator View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem of the implementation of UITableViewCell's separator.

As you can see from the screenshot, there is a white gap visible before the separator, I think that is because I set the bg colour of the cell as light grey and also I put the inset of the separator as 53.

My first attempt was instead of using the separator, I was trying to draw the lines at the end of the cell by my self. But since on selection of the row the content of the row get updated, and there is a lot of issue regarding the calculation of the height of the cell.

So basically it is really hard for me to draw the line pixel precise at the end of the cell.

This left me the option to access the cell's separator's view, which currently not aware of any easy way, and fill the gap with my default background colour of the table.

My question is, how can I access the separator view

Or

Do I have any other alternatives to implement what I want?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Instead of the white, what do you want to see? Try setting the table view's background color to whatever color you wish to see instead of white.

Comment: Are you setting the color of each cell's background view or content view?

Comment: @esker I think you are right, I changed my contentView background colour. It is working fine now.

Comment: Guys, should I close this question or you guys answer then I take your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView doesn't provide APIs to access or modify the cells separator view directly. However, it has methods to change it's color, style, etc. Most of the times, though, the only solution for a custom separator is to draw it yourself, or better, to set the cell's backgroundView property to a simple view with a line subview or layer in it (a subview, although has some overhead, gives you the flexibility of autoresizing automatically using autoresizing masks or auto layout).

e.g.

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(backgroundView.bounds) - 1, CGRectGetWidth(backgroundView.bounds), 1.0f];

[lineView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)];
[backgroundView addSubview:lineView];

cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this workaround:

Put UIImageView at bottom edge of cell and you can set image as per your requirement

**STEP 1:** Set divider as per image
[image: Set divider Y postion as per your cell]

**STEP 2:** Set Separator style to none

[image: Select TableView and from Attribute Inspector]

Answer (score -1):

Since iOS 7 you can use this

`cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`